# Outlook crashes after adding second account after upgrading to iOS 9 on iPhone 6

Tags: applications, ios

Does any body know any solutions to solve the problem of Outlook for iOS crashes after adding second email account on it when the iPhone 6 was upgraded to iOS9?

Comment: What version of the Outlook app? It could just be a bug they need to fix. Hard to tell if the app is updated for iOS 9 from your details.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way I had to resolve this issue was to delete the application and then reinstall it from the App store.

To do this, on the screen with the Outlook app, press and hold the icon until it starts shaking, then click the 'x' in the top left hand corner. Then go to the App Store and redownload the app.

You'll need to do the configuration of it again unfortunately, but it shouldn't take too long.

Comment: i did reinstall it is still crashing .

Comment: Can we assume you have two accounts working properly with the shipping version of the app or is this more a "try this" to troubleshoot?